# Jitsi - meet framework configuration in iOS

Tags: ios, jitsi, jitsi-meet

How to configure Jitsi-meet framework in iOS swift project to enable video call service?

Comment: Have you checked this url? https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/ios

Comment: Yes, But getting error in podfile and jitsimeet.framework and webrtc.framework files are missing.

Comment: After adding pods, you must close the project and open .xcworkspace

Comment: Thank u.... Pod installed successfully... I just cleaned the build folder and closed the project

Comment: I am going to add my comment as a answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding pods, you must close the project and open .xcworkspace. And don't forgot to clean the build folder using "command + alt + shift + k".

Comment: Pod error is solved but I just want to know how to use this framework independently in my iOS project.Now its working with react native implementation.

Comment: what is the name of the pod? its giving error by adding it in podfile using 'pod jitsimeet' or 'pod jitsi-meet'.

Comment: @aBilal17 i want the pod name for my native standalone ios application. The link you have provided is of react native. please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT : This is also working for Xcode `Version 12.2 (12B45b)` on Mac OS Big Sur.

---

For anyone who want to embed jitsi meet iOS SDK with swift app, Following steps worked for me in Xcode `Version 11.3.1 (11C505)`

1. Clone the jitsi-meet repository from [Github](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet)
2. install the necessary dependencies using `npm install`
3. install the necessary pods using, `cd ios && pod install && cd ..`
4. Then execute the following command to build up jitsi meet framework files. `xcodebuild -workspace ios/jitsi-meet.xcworkspace -scheme JitsiMeet -destination='generic/platform=iOS' -configuration Release archive`
5. Above command will generate `JitsiMeet.framework` folder inside `\ios\sdk`. (if you see a shortcut here, Please navigate to original location.)
6. Create a new folder (Something like frameworks) inside your project and copy `JitsiMeet.framework` to that folder
7. Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-webrtc/ios/WebRTC.framework` and copy `WebRTC.framework` to frameworks folder inside your app.
8. Then navigate to `Targets > Your project` and navigate to `Link Binary with Libraries` and press little plus button and select `Add files` from the dropdown menu in the bottom and add the `JitsiMeet.framework` and `WebRTC.framework` from frameworks folder inside your project.
   [image: Link Binary with Libraries]
9. Remember to change `ENABLE_BITCODE` to `NO` and `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES`
10. Navigate to `Targets > General` and change the `Frameworks, Libraries and Embed Content` and change the `Embed` to `Embed without signing` or `Embed with signing`
    [image: Embed without signing]
11. Voila ! now import `JitsiMeet` and you are good to go.

For more information refer [Jitsi Handbook](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-ios-sdk)

Comment: How can we use this cusotmised SDK on react native app