# Fast way to make framework and add it to a project with xcodebuild

Tags: swift, xcodebuild

I want to create a framework and add it to a project.
[jitsimeet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/ios) is the project I want to make framework from.
As it is says in the [jitsimeet](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/ios) page, I have to execute this command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/jitsi-meet.xcworkspace -scheme JitsiMeet -destination='generic/platform=iOS' -configuration Release archive
```

with this command I can have the framework. But this takes a long time around 30 minuets.

- How can I do this with shorter time?
- Can I add a framework without making archive?

Comment: Why dont use cocoapods?

Comment: @J.Doe This project is on cocoapods. and I want to change the code.

Comment: You can fork the project, change the code, push it to your repo and you can than work with that pod with your code

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks. but there is no way to do this with xcodebuild but faster?

Comment: this will work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809255/7704650